# how to refresh PivotTable automatically?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question about, how do I refresh the PivotTable automatically?
yes, i know this simple code : `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`
can do that, but requires that I open the sheet that has the PivotTable in it.
I don't want it, I want it to run automatically without bothering to open a data source that has a PivotTable in it.

Comment: You cannot. What you can do is open the wb with the pivot from the wb in which you want to use the data, refresh and close.

Comment: *"requires that I open the sheet"* actually it just requires you to open the workbook not the sheet.

Comment: "but requires that I open the sheet that has the PivotTable in it." - if you don't open the sheet, you can't see the pivot table. Why would you update it if you don't watch it?